# Django user delete privilege role

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

Is possible to give roles/group to admin users to delete only the users they created?

For example:
admin1 created user1, user2
admin2 created user3, user4

admin1 should only have permissions to delete user1 and user2 and not have any access to user3 and user4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in user model you can add the file creator `ForeignKey` to admin:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ......
```

when admin delete user check the creator:

```
def userDelete(request, userId):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=userId)
    if user.creator == request.user:  // have access
        article.delete()
    messages.success(request, 'User Delete')  
    return redirect('***:***')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since changing the user model mid-project may result in [complications](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project), another approach to extend the existing User model can be:

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='custom_user')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

And now you can use the `created_by` field as mentioned by @ming in their answer.